# How to force ELECTRON_NO_ATTACH_CONSOLE in production Electron app?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

Im about to launch an Electron app, although i've just discovered that when you run the app from the command line in Windows the terminal session attaches to the log output from the Electron app. You can't quit the terminal session because it will kill the app.

I need my app to be launched on startup of Windows, without having the ugly terminal screen there.  I would also like people to be able to script it's start without needing the terminal to stay alive.

I know I can do this with the `ELECTRON_NO_ATTACH_CONSOLE` env var, but I can't figure out how to force this to be always on. I dont want to tell people they need to `set ELECTRON_NO_ATTACH_CONSOLE=true` before running the app, thats ugly.

Can anyone help me here?  I tried putting `process.env.ELECTRON_NO_ATTACH_CONSOLE=true` at the top of my main.js file but it did nothing.

Using Electron builder to build the production app.

Comment: This seems like a nice `feature-request`.

Comment: are you running in linux machine ?

Comment: you can try to use dotenv https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv to set this variable in a .env file or you can write a startscript that first set the variable and then start the app.

Comment: This is in Windows ...  But possibly also Mac and Linux, only tested this on Windows.
Does dotenv hook in before the electron.js startup?  Because i tried setting the env before loading any libs